# Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\ln(1+\tan{x})$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to find the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=\ln(1+\tan {x})$. I tried it by successively differentiating it up to four times but it is very time consuming.

Comment: It is not a "nice" expansion as you can see by just checking WolframAlpha ([**link**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maclaurin+Series+for+ln(1%2Btanx)))

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of work, I think that composition of series is a simple way
$$\tan(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+\frac{17 x^7}{315}+O\left(x^9\right)$$
Let $t$ to be the above development and use
$$\log(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}-\frac{t^4}{4}+\cdots$$ and use the binomial expansion (stopping when you find powers of $x$ greater than $7$ to get
$$\ln(1+\tan{(x)})=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{2 x^3}{3}-\frac{7 x^4}{12}+\frac{2 x^5}{3}-\frac{31
   x^6}{45}+\frac{244 x^7}{315}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
Notice that using this process, we could continue for ever; for example
$$\sin (\log (\tan (x)+1))=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{13 x^5}{60}-\frac{23
   x^6}{360}-\frac{271 x^7}{2520}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\tan (\sin (\log (\tan (x)+1)))=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5 x^3}{6}-\frac{5 x^4}{6}+\frac{11 x^5}{10}-\frac{229
   x^6}{180}+\frac{323 x^7}{210}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ and so on.

Answer (score 3):

According to [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003707), the series can be written as $$\log (1+\tan x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n,$$ where $$a_n = \sum_{m=0}^{(n-1)/2} \sum_{j=0}^{2m} \binom{j+n-2m-1}{n-2m-1} \frac{(j+n-2m)!}{n-2m} \, 2^{2m-j} (-1)^{n-m+j-1} \left\{{n} \atop {j+n-2m}\right\}$$ where $\{{a \atop b}\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  Numeric calculation with *Mathematica* supports this; e.g.,

```
S[u_] := (Range[u + 1] - 1)! CoefficientList[Normal[Series[Log[1 + Tan[x]],
         {x, 0, u}]], x] - Table[Sum[Binomial[j + n - 2 m - 1, n - 2 m - 1]
         (j + n - 2 m)! 2^(2 m - j) (-1)^(n - m + j - 1) StirlingS2[n,
         j + n - 2 m]/(n - 2 m), {m, 0, (n - 1)/2}, {j, 0, 2 m}], {n, 0, u}]
```

Then `S[50]` for example gives a list of zeros, indicating equality.

Comment: May I ask ? How did you find it ? What is amazing is the asymptotics given in the EOIS page. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I used *Mathematica* to numerically compute $a_n$ for $n \le 10$ using `Series[]` and then used OEIS to search for the sequence, which brought me to that page and the rest of the information.  If you read the linked preprint by Kruchinin, it tells you a lot about how the formula was obtained.  As for the asymptotics, I have no clue.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici [Possibly related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Formal_power_series_version).